# How to get JQuery realtime value of a input field?

Tags: jquery

```
var len = 160 - $(this).val.length;
```

I get same value foreach key press on target input..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are asking the length of the val function (which will always be 1), instead of calling it and asking the length of what it returns. Try this:

```
var len = 160 - $(this).val().length
```

To illustrate this on Stackoverflow that conveniantly uses jQuery. Observe what would happen if you did the following:

```
console.log( $("input").val )          // [function definition of val]
console.log( $("input").val() )        // "search"
console.log( $("input").val.length )   // 1
console.log( $("input").val().length ) // 6
```

So say we want to bind to the search box and log the number of characters that has been put into it we would do:

```
$("#search input").live("keyup", function(){
    console.log($(this).val().length);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

syntax error

```
var len = 160 - $(this).val().length;
```

Comment: @PaulPRO Oh, I suppose it is.  I assumed it threw an error but it just returns the val() function.